# Intent is not passing

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I having a problem in passing the intent. The code is written in proper manner still it is showing errors in the logcat. Any help will be greatfull. Thank you

Have i placed the intent code in the write area???

Here is my main file.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ProgressBar progressBar;
int progressStatus = 0;
TextView textView1, textView2;
Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.load_per);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (progressStatus < 100) {
                progressStatus += 1;
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                        textView2.setText(progressStatus + "%");
                        if (progressStatus == 100) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                                    EventActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    }
                });
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}


}
```

The logcat is showing errors like this

```
05-30 13:39:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1352): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-30 13:39:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1352): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.temp9/com.example.temp9.EventActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-30 13:39:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
05-30 13:39:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
05-30 13:39:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
05-30 13:39:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
05-30 13:39:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-30 13:39:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-30 13:39:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
05-30 13:39:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-30 13:39:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-30 13:39:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-30 13:39:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-30 13:39:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-30 13:39:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1352): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-30 13:39:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at com.example.temp9.EventActivity.onCreate(EventActivity.java:22)
05-30 13:39:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-30 13:39:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-30 13:39:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
05-30 13:39:51.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: your NPE in EventActivity.java at line 22

Comment: have you defined your EventActivity in AndroidManifest.xml????

Comment: Post your `EventActivity` file

Comment: Show your activity_main layout file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is **Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException**

Here **com.example.temp9.EventActivity.onCreate(EventActivity.java:22)** in EventActivity class' onCreate function at line 22 location you are accessing some null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you haven't added `EventActivity` in `AndroidManifest.xml`(failed to start activity message in logcat). Make sure you have added the activity in Manifest file.